# itextpdf : Css is missing while converting from HTML Source code to PDF

Tags: itext

I am trying to generate pdf from HTML code, but it is not working fine,.CSS is missing totally while generating pdf. I have written the code in c#, .net core, and OS windows 10. Following code is used to generate pdf and You can see the output result as well

```
string htmlCode = "";
string url  = "https://www.wikipedia.org/";
Uri url1 = new Uri(url);
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    htmlCode = client.DownloadString(url1);
}
using (FileStream pdfDest = System.IO.File.Open("output.pdf",
        FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
    iText.Html2pdf.HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(htmlCode, pdfDest);
}
```

It is generating multiple pages in pdf instead of a single page.
[image: First Page][image: Second Page][image: Third Page]

Comment: Looking at the code one immediately sees that the `HtmlConverter` has no knowledge of the URL of the HTML you feed it; thus, it has no chance to resolve any relative URLs in it. Have you tried telling it using `ConverterProperties` method `SetBaseUri`?

Comment: Yes, I tried with SetBaseUri, but getting the same result. I think CSS is applying but may be due to js code, it is generating like that.

I also tried with creating some template and generated pdf..css is added, but a blank page was generated.

Comment: *"I think CSS is applying but may be due to js code, it is generating like that."* - That's possible. As far as I know `HtmlConverter` does not run JavaScript code.

Comment: And what about, extra blank page? all the content was rendered on the first page of pdf, but an extra blank is generated.